# Why does Azure Automation store individual jobs in a deployment template, and can I remove them without damaging the deployment template?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I have schedules in Azure Automation that run a PowerShell script to remove batches of rows from Azure Table Storage. I was looking at using a deployment template to add schedules for other environments and noticed that I had a large number of JSON objects with a name like:

`[parameters('jobs_7d50108e_270d_456a_04da_b79cbe13ba12_name')]`

This appears to be an individual instance of an automation job, as I can see the individual schedule and runbook information. It doesn't appear to have much information in it:

`{
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/subscription-id/resourcegroups/resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/AutomationInstance/jobSchedules/job-schedule-id'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/jobSchedules",
            "name": "[parameters('jobs_7d50108e_270d_456a_04da_b79cbe13ba12_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
            "properties": {
                "runbook": {
                    "name": "MyRunBook"
                },
                "schedule": {
                    "name": "MySchedule"
                },
                "parameters": null
            },
            "resources": [],
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_AutomationInstance_name'))]"
            ]
        }`

Why is this being added to the deployment template (perhaps just for history)? Are there potentially bad effects if I remove them from the template?

Comment: I think you are safe to remove them. They look like individual instances of the job execution, like you've said for history, I've certainly not taken them over migrating them or setting up pre-configured Azure Automation accounts before so I think it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

A `jobSchedule` in Azure Automation is an association between a runbook and a schedule. Without a jobSchedule, the ARM template, when deployed, will set up any runbooks and schedules defined in the template, but without jobSchedules in the template, no runbooks will execute automatically based on those schedules.

The `[parameters('jobs_7d50108e_270d_456a_04da_b79cbe13ba12_name')]` line is just used to determine what the name of that jobSchedule will be, since every resource in ARM must be referenced by a name.